# One infinite series question, two different result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

The 1st way:
$$f(x)=\frac{4x}{x^2+2x-3}=\frac{3x-3+x+3}{(x+3)(x-1)}=\frac{3}{x+3}+\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{3}}-\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty{(\frac{-x}{3})^i}-\sum_{i=0}^\infty{x^i}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty{[(\frac{-1}{3})^i-1]}x^i$$
The 2nd way:
$$f(x)=\frac{4x}{x^2+2x-3}=x[\frac{(x+3)-(x-1)}{(x+3)(x-1)}]=x[\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+3}]=x[-\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{3}}-\frac{1}{1-x}]=x[-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^\infty{(\frac{-x}{3})^i}-\sum_{i=0}^\infty{x^i}]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty{[(\frac{-1}{3})^{i+1}-1]}x^{i+1}$$
The calculation seems right, but I get 2 different result.

Comment: a series its a kind of "infinite sum", but there is no "infinite series".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't checked your calculations but the two sums have equal value.

The first sum has one element more than the second, the element with i=0. But this element's value is $(1-1)x^0$ which is $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand it.